# select tag syntaxt error rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to write a rails `select_tag` like below, but I am getting a syntax error.

```
 <%=select_tag "Weight", options_for_select([ "500gms", "1kg" ]), :prompt => "Select Weight ", {:style=>'color:#FFFFFF;',
 :class => "pull-left margin-clear btn btn-sm btn-default-transparent btn-animated"}%>
```

I am trying to give an inline css as well. What's the error here?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: `syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting => ...ult-transparent btn-animated"});@output_buffer.safe_append=' ... `

Comment: Did you try to run after removing `:class` block ?

Comment: I need the `class` block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
<%=select_tag "Weight", options_for_select([ "500gms", "1kg" ]), :prompt => "Select Weight ",:style=>'color:#FFFFFF;',
:class => "pull-left margin-clear btn btn-sm btn-default-transparent btn-animated" %>
```